# Tabs Not Styled

Tags: android

I want to make 2 tabs both contain fragments and have swipe functionality. I have got everything working however the tabs are not styled.

[image]

I want to use the holo light theme and have defined this in my manifest like so...

```
  <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

As for customizing you can use the style generator download the file and copy it into your project its an easy way to create the basics.

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    ...

    // Specify that tabs should be displayed in the action bar.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create a tab listener that is called when the user changes tabs.
    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // show the given tab
        }

        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // hide the given tab
        }

        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
            // probably ignore this event
        }
    };

    // Add 3 tabs, specifying the tab's text and TabListener
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText("Tab " + (i + 1))
                        .setTabListener(tabListener));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste some source code/samples. It is a good practice on StackOverflow to have it copied here so that if the website changes or is offline anyone can have access to the solution.